# SSRS report with SSAS as the data source performance bottleneck

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, sql-server-data-tools, cube, sql-server-profiler

I've searched web and StackOverflow for a long time but it was not useful for me.

I created an SSRS Report which uses Cube as Data Source. In SSMS the cube's query is fast and about Maximum 4 seconds, but the report shows the results after 1 minute.

I used SQL Server Profiler on Cube and I understood that Serializing the Results is the most time-consuming event on my report. First of all, I didn't find any solution to decrease "serialize the result" events and then I don't know how to improve my server utilization because despite of this slow report, its resource utilization (CPU, NETWORK, MEMORY) is at most 5 percent !!

by the way, my report returns about 300 thousand rows in every execution. (ROWS_RETURNED ~ 300000)

Mdx Query

```
 SELECT NON EMPTY{[Measures].Members} ON COLUMNS, NONEMPTY ( ( NONEMPTY((STRTOSET(@BankSelect))) * NONEMPTY ( STRTOSET(@BranchSelect) ) * NONEMPTY  ( STRTOSET(@DimTimeShamsiFullDate))* NONEMPTY ( (STRTOSET(@BranchTypeSelect) )) *  NONEMPTY ( (STRTOSET(@StateSelect) )) * NONEMPTY ((STRTOSET(@CitySelect)) * NONEMPTY (STRTOSET(@RowTypeSelect))) * NONEMPTY ( (STRTOSET(@MoneyStatusSelect))) * NONEMPTY ((STRTOSET(@MoneyTypeSelect))) * NONEMPTY ((STRTOSET(@MoneyUnitNameSelect)) ) )) ON ROWS FROM (SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DateInFrom)) ON COLUMNS FROM [SinapDW]) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Thank you.

Comment: Please include the MDX query

Comment: could it be parameter sniffing?

Comment: @Harry I Know lots of StrToSet and parameters make report slow, but the report is dynamic and I had to use them.

Comment: @GregGalloway I wrote my Dataset's MDX query.

Comment: @masoumeh you've already done the optimizations I was going to suggest (`CELL PROPERTIES VALUE`). I think omitting the `DIMENSION PROPERTIES` clause means you return only the MEMBER_CAPTION property for each of your dimension attributes which is the minimum you can return. I suspect it's just a large resultset so takes some time to serialize and send over the network.

Comment: @GregGalloway Thanks for your time and consideration. I agree with you about the large data set.  Isn't there any optimization solution to do with network or server utilization to improve performance?

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is network serialization or performance I would suggest having a look at the performance whitepaper on how to optimize the network packets SSAS sends. These documents provide insights on how to optimise resource usage for SSAS and also how to use its inner settings for optimisations based on your workloads.

[SQL SSAS 2008R2](https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/5/6/6567c845-fc8d-4d62-920f-c027a349c889/ssasperfguide2008r2.pdf)

[SQL SSAS 2012 & 2014](http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/2/0/d20e1c5f-72ea-4505-9f26-fef9550efd44/analysis%20services%20molap%20performance%20guide%20for%20sql%20server%202012%20and%202014.docx)

Comment: both of my servers (SSAS & SSRS) are on the same server. Does changing the network configuration help?

Comment: So those whitepapers speak about network optimisation but not only that, it also speaks about workload customisation for SSAS to optimise how it can use the resources of the machine and how does it handle its buffers for when it outputs results. These can help you so SSAS knows i can use more resources or more thread or only these CPUs, what are my limits how much of the memory can i consume before i start using disk storage etc.